# Source Generator not functioning with XAML files in .NET 6

Tags: c#, .net-core, sourcegenerators

Recently migrating some .NET 472 projects to .NET 6. One of these projects is a WPF project, but for some reason, after migration, my Source Generator does not function correctly. I receive the message:

`error CS0101: The namespace already contains a definition for type`

Indicating that the generator is trying to run twice, perhaps? If I turn the variable `IncludePackageReferencesDuringMarkupCompilation` to false, it shows an error indicating the variable was never declared (makes sense).

After looking thru google, someone indicated that this only happens after adding XAML files to the project, which I confirmed independently against a test project: The project builds normally until I added a XAML window to the project.

I'm guessing this is something to do with how WPF projects are compiled in a 2-stage mode, but I'd appreciate any suggestion on how to get Source Generators working with XAML in .NET 6.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some googling I found a couple of github issues with the same problem:

https://github.com/microsoft/CsWin32/issues/601

This seems to be a regression bug with the current release of .NET SDK 6.0.302, and the fix is either a slight change to the proj file or downgrade to 301.